how to find out the parent dependency and child dependency in springboot application with intellij
I am not able to find out the dependency of parent dependency
can we get parent dependency through version of dependency?
or can I install any plugin for this?
what is concept of inheritance in dependency ?
what is the concept of overriding concept in dependency ?
I am not able to find out the dependency of parent dependency
I want to  know which is the parent dependency and which one is child dependency in pom.xml
